# Load data into local storage once?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I am using backbone.js I need a very simple way to render a local json file into the users local storage only one time. I am building a cordova app and I just want to work with local storage data.

I have hard coded a decent size .json file (list of players) into my collection, and I just want to load the .json file into the local storage if local storage on that device is empty which will only be once, upon initialization of the app.

I could use ajax, but I don't know how to write it to only inject data one time as "starter" data. So if you know how to do this I can upload the json file to my server and somehow fetch it.

I can inject the data if I go through a series of tasks, I have to disable the `fetch` method and render this code below in an each statement, plus the json has to be hardcoded into the collection, with a certain format.

```
playersCollection.create({
  name: player.get('name'),
  team: player.get('team'),
  team_id: player.get('team_id'),
  number: player.get('number'),
  points: player.get('points')  
})
```

I am trying to finish this lol I need to use it tonight to keep stats, I am almost there the structure works, when data is loaded I can add stats etc, but I need to get that data loaded, I pray someone can help!

**Edit:** I was able to put together some sloppy code last minuet that at least worked, thanks to @VLS I will have a much better solution, but Ill post the bad code I used.

```
// I fire renderData method on click
events: {
    'click .renderData':'renderData'
},

// Inside my render method I check if "players-backbone" is in local storage
render: function() {
    var self = this;

    if (localStorage.getItem("players-backbone") === null) {
        alert('yup null');
        //playersCollection.fetch();
        this.$el.append('<button class="renderData">Dont click</button>')
    } else {
        alert('isnt null');
        this.$el.find('.renderData').remove();
        playersCollection.fetch();
    }

    this.teams.each(function(team) {
        var teamView = new TeamView({ model: team });
        var teamHtml = teamView.render().el;

        console.log($(''))

        var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')})

        _.each(teamPlayers, function(player) {
            var playerView = new PlayerView({ model: player });

            var playerHtml = playerView.render().el;
            $(teamHtml).append(playerHtml);

        }, this);

        this.$el.append(teamHtml);

    }, this);

    return this;
},

// method that populates local storage and fires when you click a button with the class .renderData
renderData: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.teams.each(function(team) {

        var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')})

        _.each(teamPlayers, function(player) {

            playersCollection.create({
              name: player.get('name'),
              team: player.get('team'),
              team_id: player.get('team_id'),
              number: player.get('number'),
              points: player.get('points')  
            })

        }, this);

    }, this);

    playersCollection.fetch();

    return this;
}
```

This is obviously not the best way to go about it, but it worked and I was in such a hurry. The caveats are you have to click a button that populates the data, the collection is hard coded in, it's just overall not very elegant (but it works) the app did what it needed.

So big thanks to @VLS, I appreciate the effort to explain your code, and create a fiddle. Sorry I was so late!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend your collection's `fetch` method and use it in conjunction with Backbone.localStorage, so inside your collection you'd have something like:

```
localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("TestCollection"),

fetch: function(options) {
    // check if localStorage for this collection exists
    if(!localStorage.getItem("TestCollection")) {
        var self = this;
        // fetch from server once
        $.ajax({
            url: 'collection.json'
        }).done(function(response) {
            $.each(response.items, function(i, item) {
                self.create(item);  // saves model to local storage
            });
        });
    } else {
        // call original fetch method
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    }        
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5nz8p/

More on Backbone.localStorage: https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage

Comment: Sorry for being so late on this, this really helps, and is much better than what I ended up writing (check OP). I was in rush to finish up, I am just thankful it worked out, this code will be much better long term. Again thanks.

Comment: We can mark this as solved, but if you don't mind.. I don't remember seeing on the docs specifically where to put the `fetch` method. Should it be inside the collection, it makes more sense, but I accidentally put it in my view (actually think I saw a local storage to-do list tutorial doing it). This is probably preference? Either way I am sure I will figure it out, and ill console log what arguments the fetch method accepts. Still super new, got a lot of learning to do today. Thanks for this though.

Comment: Yes, this goes inside your collection; check how the fiddle is set up. The advantage of this is that you can continue using `fetch` in your application without needing to remember to check localStorage each time inside your view.